# Is STL size() runs on constant complexity or Linear?

Tags: c++, stl

**Which is more efficient and which is more convenient to use ?**

```
    std::vector<int> V(Some Integers);

    1)

    for(int i=0 ; i<V.size() ; ++i){
         std::cout<<V[i]<<" "; // print all integers
    }

    2)

    int size=V.size();
    for(int i=0 ; i<size ; ++i){
      std::cout<<V[i]<<" "; // printing all integers
    }
```

Comment: `std::vector::size()` is `O(1)` (constant) complexity. I would expect (1) and (2) to be indistinguishable in release build; an optimizer should be able to hoist `size()` calls out of the loop.

Comment: But Standard only says that it is of O(1) complexity. It may return a stored size value or calculate `end - begin` pointers difference. And anyway if you turn `inline`s off (like in debug builds), the first way will call functions. The second way is more reliable to be fast.

Comment: I'd suggest `for (const auto& elem : V)`. Not only is it guaranteed to only evaluate the "end condition" once. It is also far easier to read.

Answer (score 5):

That depends on the container and c++ standard used. For example, `std::set::size()` in `C++03` could work in up to linear complexity. As for `C++14`, `size()` of all frequently used containers (at least, `vector`, `list`, `set`, `map`, `unordered_set`, `unordered_map`, `queue` and `deque`) runs in constant time.

Comment: Addition: As an aside, iterating from begin() to end() is more generally efficient, and using a for-range-loop more idiomatic. Also, +1.

Comment: The exception you are looking for is [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list), which does not have `size()`.

Comment: For those of you who are curious as to why this is the case, in 23.1 `size()` is not mandated to have constant complexity since it says "should have" instead of "shall". Welcome to language lawyer hell.

Comment: @Deduplicator More efficient than what? Is iterating from `begin()` to `end()` not the same as `std::distance(s.begin(), s.end())` which has linear complexity?

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper Using iterators for iterating is generally more efficient than indexing.

Answer (score 0):

`size` usually runs in constant time. The main concern is whether it will run. The compiler could recognize that nothing you do is changing the size, but it could fail to do so. In that case, you could have a function call each iteration, which even in constant time might (or not) be slower than a simple integer comparison.

If you have a complex container (not a vector, where the size is most probably a simple variable already), and you are doing complex things to its elements (where you're not changing the size, but there's a chance the compiler won't realize it), and you're extremely strapped for time (loop executed millions of times), then it could make sense to use the second version.

Comment: Or to rephrase: optimize only if it's a bottleneck and the compiler isn't smart enough.

Comment: Yes you could summarize to that :)